# firebase v3 signInWithPopup google login internal error

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, firebase

I an trying to perform "signInWithPopup" using google account in a new firebase app (V3). The frontend uses angularjs and the way I am trying to perform the authentication:

```
$scope.login_managment = function() {
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup($scope.provider)
      .then((function(_this) {
        return function(result) {
          $scope.token = result.credential.accessToken;
          $scope.currUser = result.user;
          console.log($scope.currUser);
        };
      }).catch(function(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      });
    };
```

But whenever I rty to run it, (even from the registered site on firebaseapp.com), I am getting:

> **{code: "auth/internal-error", message: "An internal error has
>   occurred."}**

I have tried to declare the site in the Auth section on firebase console, and on the Auth section in google developers console, but I am still getting this message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is in production? If not, Try to create a new firebase app and test from it. I dont know why, but works. Maybe a bug, remember that is the first week of firebase 3.x.

Comment: I prefer to use this app, as most of the code was written and assigned to my domain already

Answer (score 0):

What is $scope.provider? The old way accepted a string, but it now needs be a return of a new function provided by firebase

```
var auth = firebase.auth();

var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
   // User signed in!
   var uid = result.user.uid;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error occurred
});
```

Source: [Firebase new documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#update_your_authentication_code_numbered)

Comment: $scop.provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();